# PHP no permission to read or write to file when running from cronjob

Tags: php, linux, permissions, cron

I have a PHP script that has to be run every 15 minutes on the server (Ubuntu 16.04). It runs just fine from the command line or browser, but it doesn't from cron. The problem is, that its not logging and deleting a file.

PHP script:

```
<?php

require ("cijfercheck_pass.php");
include ("postmessage.php");
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://rapid.deltion.nl/user/login/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'username='.urlencode($login_email).'&password='.urlencode($login_pass).'&login=Login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/my_cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/my_cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://rapid.deltion.nl/student/info/");
$page = curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://rapid.deltion.nl/student/pdfresultaten/id/97041344/Luuk%20Wuijster.pdf');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'btnresultatenpdf='.urlencode('pdf resultaten'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/my_cookies.txt");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$destination = dirname(__FILE__) . '/pdf/temp.pdf';
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fputs($file, $result);
fclose($file);

function logdata($body){
    $time = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
    $file = 'cijfercheck.log';
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    $current .= "[${time}] ${body} \n";
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
}

if (file_exists('pdf/temp.pdf')) {
    logdata("temp.pdf gedownload van rapid.deltion.nl");
} else {
    logdata("ERROR: kon temp.pdf niet downloaden van rapid.deltion.nl");
    die();
}

$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdf1 = $parser->parseFile('pdf/cijferlijst.pdf');
$pdf2 = $parser->parseFile('pdf/temp.pdf');

$string1 = $pdf1->getText();
$string2 = $pdf2->getText();

$nospace1 = str_replace(' ', '', $string1);
$nospace2 = str_replace(' ', '', $string2);

$arr1 = explode(':', $nospace1);
$arr2 = explode(':', $nospace2);

$check = $arr1[5];
$temp = $arr2[5];

if (!empty($temp) OR !empty($check)) {
    logdata("pdf omgezet naar een array");
} else {
    logdata("ERROR: was niet mogelijk om pdf om te zetten naar array");
    die();
}

if($check == $temp){

    if(unlink('pdf/temp.pdf')){
        logdata("temp.pdf is verwijderd");
    } else {
        logdata("ERROR: kon temp.pdf niet verwijderen");
        die();
    }

} else {
    if(unlink('pdf/cijferlijst.pdf') && rename('pdf/temp.pdf', 'pdf/cijferlijst.pdf')){
        logdata("cijferlijst.pdf is verwijderd en temp.pdf is hernoemt naar cijferlijst.pdf");
        PostToSlack();
    } else {
        logdata("ERROR: kon cijferlijst.pdf niet verwijderen en/of kon temp.pdf niet hernoemen naar cijferlijst.pdf");
    }

}
```

The crontab entry:

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * php /var/www/html/slack/cijfercheck/cijfercheck.php
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: The account that the CRON job is running under must also have persissions to access relevant folders/files. Remember it wont be the same account that your web server or your terminal runs under

Comment: I am running it as root, so does that mean root does not have enough permissions?

Comment: In that case I can only say "Are you sure its running as root"

Comment: Yes because this is what the CRON job logs say:

Dec 10 15:45:01 h2624478 CRON[1810]: (root) CMD (php /var/www/html/slack/cijfercheck/cijfercheck.php)

Comment: I copied your code into your question. Please make sure your question is self-contained. Off-site resources can be used to enhance the question, but they shouldn't be required to understand it. The easiest way to format a code block on SO is to paste your code, then select it and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button. This indents the whole block by an additional four spaces, instructing Stack Overflow to format it as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed`enter code here
```

it looks like you has missing username, try:

```
*/15 * * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/slack/cijfercheck/cijfercheck.php
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that was actually not the problem, I already fixed it. I forgot that I had to use absolute paths... :/